# select cumulative (?) count where count depends on two date columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to record how the number of the bugs being solved changes over time. To explain better, below I make a table:

```
current_status  begin_date   finish_date 
begin           2020-11-20   None 
begin           2020-11-21   None
done            2020-11-22   2020-11-23 
done            2020-11-23   2020-11-25 
done            2020-11-23   2020-11-25   
done            2019-11-24   2020-11-26
```

For example, on the date 2020-11-22 there are 3 bugs being solved, because finish date of each of them is later than 2020-11-22. Complete result below:

```
date        count_begin
2020-11-20  1
2020-11-21  2
2020-11-22  3
2020-11-23  4
2020-11-24  5
2020-11-25  3
2020-11-26  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the dates using `generate_series()` and the either a subquery or `join`/`group by`:

```
select gs.dte, count(t.begin_date)
from generate_series('2020-11-20'::date, '2020-11-26'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     t
     on begin_date <= gs.dte and
        (finish_date is null or finish_date >= ts.date)
group by gs.dte
order by gs.dte;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, are some of the namings typos? `start_dte` --> `begin_date`, `end_dte` --> `finish_date`, and `ts.date` --> `gs.dte`. Are these the namings you meant?